# nested transition end events

Tags: javascript, css, nested, transition

I'm trying to do several css transitions after one another. The thing is, the inner event listener will fire immediately when the first transition ends, so it does not wait for its assigned event to run. Does it have something to do with capturing? I can't figure out what's the reason for this behavior.

```
//do somehting on elem1 that triggers css transitionend
elem1.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    //do something on elem2
    elem2.addEventListener("transitionend", function (){
        //do something
    });
});
```

To give an example: I want to pop up an element by sizing it with a transition and then, with completion, fade in its content object with another transition.

Comment: I don’t understand your problem description. (Of course the `transitionend` fires when the transition ends, when else would you expect it to fire?) — _“I want to pop up an element by sizing it with a transition and then, with completion, fade in its content object with another transition”_ – I don’t see why that would need any scripting at all. You know how long your first transition takes – so can’t you simply use `transition-delay` with an equal value on your second one, so that it only starts to do stuff when the first one has already finished …?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, for clarification: I got two elements, _container_ which is div, and _content_ which is an object tag inside the div. I want to size the container with a transition and then, after it is full-sized, I want to blend in the content element. So what I expect is, that the container is sized, its transitionend is triggered and this function will blend in the content. After that, I want some code to be executed (inner event listener), but only when the content is visible. Hope that helps understanding.

Comment: I could use transition-delay, but I think its kind of patchy, and also I still don't understand why the inner event listener fires simultaneously with the outer.

Comment: _“I still don't understand why the inner event listener fires simultaneously with the outer”_ – without a complete example where we can look at the issue, I doubt anyone here will be able to tell you that.

Comment: Okay, I found the bug. elem1 in this case is the inner element, which I mixed up. So it is actually bubbling not capturing, stopPropagation() helped. Sorry for redundant post.